# gRPC auth_context.h using std::iterator produces deprecated warning with latest VC++ compiler

Tags: c++, grpc

Compiling one of my projects that uses gRPC with the latest Visual Studio 2019 16.5 preview 2 compiler gives rise to this warning:

```
1>D:\...\grpcpp\impl\codegen\security\auth_context.h(38,19): warning C4996: 'std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,const grpc::AuthProperty,ptrdiff_t,const grpc::AuthProperty *,const grpc::AuthProperty &>': warning STL4015: The std::iterator class template (used as a base class to provide typedefs) is deprecated in C++17. (The <iterator> header is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard has never required user-defined iterators to derive from std::iterator. To fix this warning, stop deriving from std::iterator and start providing publicly accessible typedefs named iterator_category, value_type, difference_type, pointer, and reference. Note that value_type is required to be non-const, even for constant iterators. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_ITERATOR_BASE_CLASS_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
```

Before submitting a bug report, I thought I've check here if the gRPC developers are already aware of this?

Comment: To me this looks like a bug, Google is usually aware of new standards.

Answer (score 2):

gRPC is currently dependant on Absel that is reliant on C++11.  You should avoid using two different C++ standards in your applications to avoid template incompatibilities.  There is a longer discussion on Absel C++11 vs C++17 versions here: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/issues/259.

You can check out the Absel pages for more details at https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.

Answer (score 1):

The position that gRPC doesn't support C++17 is a little surprising. I might be missing it, but I don't see any mention on the main grpc page that anything beyond C++11 isn't supported. The only support matrix I was able to find was: https://grpc.io/docs/#official-support

In general both protobuf and gRPC usage will cause a slew of warnings in Visual Studio, unrelated to this error. For generated cc files, suppressing warnings 4267, 4996, and 4244 is helpful.

For this C++17 warning/error, since the issue is in a header, you'll hit the issue on your own, non-generated cpp files. You don't want to disable such warnings/errors on every file that uses the header, because then you'll mask your own issues. I currently work around by creating `grpcpp.suppress_errors.h`:

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning ( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4996)
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#pragma warning ( pop )
```

Then instead of including `<grpcpp/grpcpp.h>`, include `grpcc.suppress_errors.h` . It's a bit silly, but it will keep your own code clean from suppressions.

Answer (score 1):

[aggieNick02's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65346451/433718) didn't fix it for me. But I could could manage to suppress the errors in Visual Studio like so:

[image]

I added `_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS;` to the preprocessor definitions.

Not as optimal as [aggieNick02's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65346451/433718), but at least this kept me going.

I got grpc from [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.info/port/grpc), if that info helps somebody:

> 1.37.0 3
> dc35791a568aacf855355bcfcdff978ec22e69d3
>
> 2021-07-27
>
> abseil (2021-03-24), c-ares (1.17.1), grpc (1.37.0), openssl (1.1.1k), protobuf (3.15.8), protobuf (3.15.8), re2 (2020-10-01), upb
> (2020-12-19), zlib (1.2.11)

Comment: Weird. I also get grpc from vcpkg (admittedly a little dated, updating to a recent commit is on my soon to-do list), so I wonder what is different. If you have a little empty project to reproduce the warning not going away I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC does not currently support C++17.  We're currently using C++11.  You should probably use whatever flags are necessary to have your compiler enforce C++11 semantics.

Comment: I'm trying to move forward a decade.:( 
If I read the warning emitted by the MS compiler correctly, it implies that the underlying code could be written to conform with the newer standard and still work with older compilers.

Comment: Yes, it probably could.  We don't consider this a bug right now, though, because we don't yet support C++17.  If you'd like to see this fixed, feel free to send us a PR.

Comment: Doing the change is not something I'd be comfortable with Mark, but it'd be nice not to have such warnings - which presumably will become errors at some point in the future.

Comment: If/when we start supporting C++17, I'm sure we'll address this.  In the interim, if it's not causing any actual problem, this isn't going to be a high priority for us to change.